# Routing Config for Web-API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am creating a Web-API service using .Net 4.5.2.

I want to have the following URIs:

- /api/v1/timeseries/{id}
- /api/v1/timeseries/approval/{id}

With this, I expect to have two controllers:

- TimeSeriesController
- TimeSeriesApprovalController

Using default routing as below, I achieve my first desired outcome (`/api/v1/timeseries/{id}`), but I'm not sure how to achieve the second outcome.  Can someone please show me how to amend the route config to deal with the second URI?

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: @mjwills: Thanks.  If you wish to transfer this to an answer I will accept it.  With regard to /TimeSeries/Approval vs /TimeSeriesApproval, is there a convention?

Comment: The `DefaultApi` you are already using is pretty much the usual convention - but there are lots of both types of examples. Choose whatever you feel works best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use your existing routes, and use the url like:

```
/api/v1/timeseriesapproval/{id}
```

Note that this perfectly matches your existing route:

```
"api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
```

where `controller` matches `timeseriesapproval`.

Another option would be to setup a new route (prior to your existing one) specific for this need:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "PutThisBeforeYourExistingOneApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/timeseries/approval/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "TimeSeriesApproval", id = RouteParameter.Optional } );
```